# spawnining more threads

Tags: java

I have developed a program in which the thread A waits for Thread B to complete it task and when thread B finishes its task it makes notfiy()  to thread A to continue onwards..below is the code..

```
    class ThreadA {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
 ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
 b.start();

 synchronized(b) {
 try {
 System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
 b.wait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
System.out.println("Total is: " + b.totals);
 }
}
}


class ThreadB extends Thread {
public  int totals;

 public void run() {
     synchronized(this) { //instance level lock
     for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
      totals += i;
      }
      notify();
      }
      }


}
```

Now I want lets say 3 more thread are waiting for thread b , so please advise me how to spawn 3 more threads , just like thread A is waiting , please advise.

Comment: You could start off by following some of the suggestions I made in your last question: get rid of the public field, *don't* extend Thread, *don't* call wait/notify on Thread objects. (They *will* confuse you.)

Comment: You should work on indenting properly(i shd too btw). it helps to read and see properly.

Comment: @jon, Yeah Man, thanks a lot i will follow, but rite now I am more concerned for my present scenario, please advise

Comment: @user1336909: What's the point of giving you a second round of advice when there's no evidence you're going to follow it, given that you've ignored the first round? Clean up what you already know how to clean up - then edit your question so it's significantly clearer. At the moment I can't make head or tail of it. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: .I want to start multiple threads let assume 3 more new threads that are waiting for thread b to finish it task first..!

Comment: @user1336909: You're still not being clear about what problems you're having, nor *exactly* what you want to happen. Take your time, explain yourself as clearly as you possibly can, *in your question*.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) it has a methode [invokeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). You can submit all your ThreadB and hold a List of Future's.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code actually contain possible deadlock since you `start()` the threadB first and it is calling the `notify()` in its `run()`. This `notify()` is possible to be called before the `wait()` in the main. If this happens, you threadB will be waiting forever.

To start more ThreadB, you just need to create more instances.

```
ThreadB threadBs = new ThreadB[3];
for (ThreadB b : threadBs) {
    b = new ThreadB();
    b.start();
}
```

However, I will suggest implementing the Runnable interface instead of just extending the Thread class.

Comment: Hi Evanwong, thanks a lot, well what if I called notify() at the start of the run() method then it throws iilegal monitor state exception...could you please explain in detail regarding deadlock , that will be a great help.I want to start multiple threads let assume 3 more new threads that are waiting for thread b to finish it task first..! please advise